# The limit of $\ln(n) - \ln(n^2 + 1)$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

As $n\to\infty$, what is the limit of

$\ln(n) - \ln(n^2 + 1)$

---

Using properties of logs and limits, I ended up with:

$$
\ln \left(\lim \left(\frac{n}{n^2 + 1}\right)\right)
$$

where lim is the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Evaluating this inside limit as 0, I am left with $\ln(0)$, which is undefined.

wolfram's answer to question is $-\infty$, not undefined.  Where did I go wrong?

Also, since the original question asks if this sequence converges or diverges... hypothetically, if a limit is undefined, what does that say about convergence or divergence?

Thank you!

Comment: $\log(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$. If $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=a$, there is no reason you should expect that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$.

Comment: For all intent and purposes $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \ln{x}=-\infty$. Check the natural log graph.

Comment: @George1811 while I do understand that, why are we looking at the limit as n --> 0?  If we pull the limit inside (as I did) and note that the limit of the inside expression goes to 0, are we now looking at the limit of ln(n) as n --> 0, and if so, why is that?

Comment: Well yes we are looking at $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} ln(0)$. But since $0$ is a constant this is equal to $\ln(0)$. Now we have to look at what happens to $\ln(x)$ as $x$ approaches zero, to know the 'value' of $\ln(0)$. For that we need limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, don't make the mistake of trying to "evaluate" the sequence at infinity, it doesn't make sense. Infinity is NOT a number. The limit of the expression inside the logarithm is zero, so as $n$ goes to infinity the logarithm goes to $-\infty$, in the sense that $\forall M>0 \exists \nu\in\mathbb{N}: a_n<M \forall n > \nu$.
For your last question, we usually say that the sequence diverges to $-\infty$. The limit is not undefined, a sequence that diverges to $-\infty$ has a limit, and it is precisely $-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just need a little more clarification here.
So if the limit of the expression inside the logarithm is zero, what does it matter what n approaches if the only thing we are looking at is ln(0)?

Comment: We're not looking at $\log(0)$. The point is that one of the reasons why limits were invented is to evaluate the behaviour of a function (or of a sequence) in points where it doesn't make much sense to evaluate it (for instance, points of discontinuity, or asymptotic behaviour). Now, keep in mind that in the whole process we're absolutely not concerning ourselves with $\log(0)$, which remains undefined. We're asking ourselves "How does the sequence behave when $n$ becomes very very large"? And the answer, in this case, is that the argument of the logarithm becomes very small (but not zero)...

Comment: ...and so the logarithm becomes a very "large" (in absolute value) negative number. I suggest you try to look at the rigorous definition of limit for sequences and functions. When you have understood it properly, it becomes enlightening.

Comment: Clearer now, this makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$\ln(n) - \ln(n^2 + 1) \le \ln(n) - \ln(n^2) = \ln(n) - 2\ln(n) =- \ln(n) \to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.